# Custom ng-enter directive not passing $event from html to the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using a custom directive that detects when the user presses enter and then **calls the same function that is called in the ngSubmit** of the surrounding form element.

Below is a demonstration of my problem, I need access to the event from within the controller but it is always undefined.

Has anyone had this issue before? What is the issue? Why is it happening? links to refs are just as good as explanations.

**Is there a better way then duplicating the method call twice? (secondary)**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('submitCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.submitContent = function(event) {
    //This is what I am looking for.
    console.log(event); //This is undefined. 
  }
}]);

app.directive('mvEnter', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind('keydown keypress', function(event) {
      if (event.which === 13) {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          scope.$eval(attrs.mvEnter);
        });
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>

<body ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller="submitCtrl">
    <textarea mv-enter="submitContent($event);"></textarea>
  </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$eval`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js#L989-L991) method looks like this `$scope.$eval(expr, locals)`, that means you can use the `locals` object of the `$eval` function, where the key will be the parameter name(`$event`).

```
scope.$eval(attrs.mvEnter, {$event: event});
```

[**Preview**](http://plnkr.co/edit/aJGpyQhDtueNCK6W8HmF?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

I changed a little your code snippet. Take a look and tell us if this worked for you! :)

Explanation: $scope.eval, as the name of the function says, evaluates the expression you passed. If the expression is a prototype of a function, the method will return the function you evaluated so you can execute it. So, you have the function to execute and the parameter you want, so... 1 + 1 = 2 jajajajaja.

I hope this helped you. If you have any question, just ask :)

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('submitCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.submitContent = function(event) {
    //This is what I am looking for.
    console.log(event); //This is undefined. 
  }
}]);

app.directive('mvEnter', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind('keydown keypress', function(event) {
      if (event.which === 13) {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          var directiveFunction = scope.$eval(attrs.mvEnter);
          if (angular.isFunction(directiveFunction)) {
            directiveFunction(event);
          }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>

<body ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller="submitCtrl">
    <textarea mv-enter="submitContent"></textarea>
  </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: While this works in the situation you have a single method called within the expression, the answer I accepted is the correct one as it works no matter the details of the expression being evaluated as long as locals are defined correctly.

Comment: Yes, im right with you. Therefore, the code marked as correct answer is cleaner than mine. I also vote that answer jajajaja.