# Pass event object from directive to callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Im using Angular 1.5.6.

I have a directive for checking for a double click:

```
angular.module('redMatter.analyse')
.directive('iosDblclick',
  function () {

      var DblClickInterval = 300; //milliseconds

      var firstClickTime;
      var waitingSecondClick = false;

      return {
          restrict: 'A',

          link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
              element.bind('click', function (e) {

                  if (!waitingSecondClick) {
                      firstClickTime = (new Date()).getTime();
                      waitingSecondClick = true;

                      setTimeout(function () {
                          waitingSecondClick = false;
                      }, DblClickInterval);
                  }
                  else {
                      waitingSecondClick = false;

                      var time = (new Date()).getTime();
                      if (time - firstClickTime < DblClickInterval) {

                          scope.$apply(attrs.iosDblclick);

                      }
                  }
              });
          }
      };
  });
```

I use this here:

```
<div ios-dblclick="onDoubleClick($event, graph)" ></div>
```

`graph` is an object inside an `ng-repeat` directive. In onDoubleClick, I need access to `$event`:

```
$scope.onDoubleClick = function($event, graph){

    console.log('in onDoubleClick and arguments are ', arguments);

    var element = $event.srcElement;
```

However I'm unsure of how to pass the event from the directive to `onDoubleClick`. In the console log, arguments prints out as:

```
[undefined, Object]
```

Where `Object` is `graph`. How can I also pass back the event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you could pass `locals` with `$eval` method, consider using it while calling `attrs.iosDblclick`. Internally it uses `$parse` API to evaluate method and uses local as a parameter.

```
scope.$eval(attrs.iosDblclick, {$event: e});
```

[**Plunker Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/5GTaOXAU10lCx5OwYSCL?p=preview)

**See also**

- [Custom ng-enter directive not passing $event from html to the controller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46177534/2435473)

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED**

http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/14470/ - working example.

So, you could pass the function to directive like this:

```
<div ios-dblclick="onDoubleClick" ios-dblclick-arg="graf" ></div>
```

inside your directive:

```
      return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        myCallback: '=iosDblclick',
        graph: '=iosDblclickArg'
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          element.bind('click', function (e) {

              if (!waitingSecondClick) {
                  firstClickTime = (new Date()).getTime();
                  waitingSecondClick = true;

                  setTimeout(function () {
                      waitingSecondClick = false;
                  }, DblClickInterval);
              }
              else {
                  waitingSecondClick = false;

                  var time = (new Date()).getTime();
                  if (time - firstClickTime < DblClickInterval) {
                      scope.myCallback(e, scope.graph)

                  }
              }
          });
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass callback to  directive as: `onDoubleClick: '&'` - *isolate scope*

```
webApp.directive('iosDblclick',
  function () {

      var DblClickInterval = 300; //milliseconds

      var firstClickTime;
      var waitingSecondClick = false;

      return {
          restrict: 'A',
          scope: {
            onDoubleClick: '&'
        },

          link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
              element.bind('click', function (e) {

                  if (!waitingSecondClick) {
                      firstClickTime = (new Date()).getTime();
                      waitingSecondClick = true;

                      setTimeout(function () {
                          waitingSecondClick = false;
                      }, DblClickInterval);
                  }
                  else {
                      waitingSecondClick = false;

                      var time = (new Date()).getTime();
                      if (time - firstClickTime < DblClickInterval) {
                          scope.onDoubleClick({data: {e:e, val: "someValue"}});
                      }
                  }
              });
          }
      };
  });
```

Where HTML is:

```
<div ios-dblclick  on-double-click="onDoubleClick(data)" ></div>
```

And controller:

```
$scope.onDoubleClick = function(data){
    var element = data.e.srcElement;
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/KIuk4loRkOA7dAhU6xb7?p=preview)</kbd>